# Validate textbox with vb.net web forma

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need help to restrict my textbox to accept just numbers. I have another textbox event textchanged and in that condition I want to not allow user to write other characters than numbers. have implemented the maxlength but I can't validate to accpet just numbers.
here is my condition that I want to implement in:

```
 Protected Sub txtIdType_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      Dim txtb As TextBox = CType(FormViewPerson.FindControl("txtIdType"), TextBox)
      Dim txtb1 As TextBox = CType(FormViewPerson.FindControl("TextBoxIDCode"), TextBox)

      If (txtb.Text = "Leternjoftimi" OrElse txtb.Text = "KosovoIDCard" OrElse txtb.Text = "Licna karta") Then
           txtb1.MaxLength = 10
      End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply in `aspx page`, like below:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumbers" runat="server" autocomplete="off" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regNumbers" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only numbers are allowed" ControlToValidate="txtNumbers" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

You don't need to use the `code-behind` for this.
Hope this helps

Comment: I need just when txtb.Text = "Leternjoftimi" txtb1 to write just numbers not for all types

Comment: Will always `txtb.Text` = `Leternjoftimi` and where you will write only numbers. Please specify your doubts clearly. As by your question you only need the textbox to allow only numbers.

Comment: Yeah just for this case (txtb.Text = "Leternjoftimi") I want the other textbox to be the maxlength = 10 and not to allow to write othercharacters than numbers

Comment: @user2568960: I guess, you should try **enb081's** solution

Answer (score 1):

You can add the validator from code behind. Try to do the following:

```
 Protected Sub txtIdType_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Dim txtb As TextBox = CType(FormViewPerson.FindControl("txtIdType"), TextBox)
            Dim txtb1 As TextBox = CType(FormViewPerson.FindControl("TextBoxIDCode"), TextBox)

            If (txtb.Text = "Leternjoftimi" OrElse txtb.Text = "KosovoIDCard" OrElse txtb.Text = "Licna karta") Then

            txtb1.MaxLength = 10
            Dim validator As New RegularExpressionValidator()
            validator.ID = "validator" + New Random().[Next](100, 1000)
            validator.ControlToValidate = CType(FormViewPerson.FindControl("TextBoxIDCode"), TextBox).ID
            validator.ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"    
            FormViewPerson.Controls.Add(validator)

            End If

        End Sub
```

> Suksese!

Comment: can you check in the browser if there is rendered a span with some ID that contains the `validator` word?

Comment: See my edit: try changing `Me.Controls.Add(validator)` to  `FormViewPerson.Controls.Add(validator)`

Comment: Thank you, but still it's not working, it allows me to write other characters not just numbers :S

Comment: @user2568960 does it allow you to write more than 10 characters?

Comment: Yes when I add this piece of code from enb081 then it allos me to write more than 10. If I let the code how it was originally it doesnt allow me to write more than 10 characters

Comment: Can you share your solution with us? Post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using this function :

```
 For Each ch As Char In txt.Text
                If Not Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                    txt.Text = ""
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
```